# How to prevent modal box to close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, dom-events

I have function that keeps track if user is active on the screen. Function is looking for `mousedown` and `keydown` events on body element. However this works fine if modal box showed on the screen and users session is still active (they can see the timer and button to extend the session). If their session expired there is message and link that will give them an option to move back to Login page. Once user session expires and they see the message with the link if they click anywhere on the page modal box is closed. I do not want modal box to close if session expired. I'm not sure why my function is not catching the step where I'm checking target element `data-type` attribute. Here is example of my function:

```
$('body').on('mousedown keydown', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);

    if(!target.is('a[data-type="sign_in"]')){
       lastActivity = new Date();
       if (dialogShowing){
          resetSessionTimeout(receiveUpdatedTimeRemaining);
       }
    }
 });
```

Code form my modal box:

```
function setupTimeoutDialog() {
        dmSessionBox.html('<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h2 class="modal-title warning">Your session is about to expire</h2><h2 class="modal-title signedout">You have been signed out</h2></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="row warning"><div class="col-xs-2"><img src="lock1.png" id="imagepreview"></div><div class="col-xs-10">Click the Continue button to extend your session.</div></div><div class="row signedout"><div class="col-xs-2"><img src="lock2.png" id="imagepreview"></div><div class="col-xs-10"><a href="Login.cfm" data-type="sign_in">Return to sign in page</a></div></div></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" id="continueButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Continue</button></div></div></div>');

        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        dmSessionBox.find('#continueButton').on('click', function() {
            log('Continue button')
            lastActivity = new Date();
            resetSessionTimeout(receiveUpdatedTimeRemaining);
        });
    }
```

Some css that I use to show hide elements:

```
#sessiontimeoutwarning {
    display: none; 
}
#sessiontimeoutwarning .signedout { 
    display: none; 
}
#sessiontimeoutwarning.signedout .signedout { 
    display: block; 
}
#sessiontimeoutwarning.signedout .warning { 
    display: none; 
}
```

And on the end function that handles screen once session is expired:

```
function showBox(showIt) {
        showIt ? $('#sessiontimeoutwarning').modal('show') : $('#sessiontimeoutwarning').modal('hide'); 
    }

function showTimeoutErrorDialog() {
        setupTimeoutDialog();
        dmSessionBox.addClass("signedout").find('button').remove();
        showBox(true); //show modal box
        dialogShowing = true;
        $("#home-container").empty();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "Ajax call to close the session",
        }).done(function(){
            console.log('Session destroied.');
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Error: "+errorThrown);
        });
    }
```

I'm not sure why modal box is closing once session expires. It should stay up on the screen. Maybe something is in there that I'm not aware about Modal Bootstrap. If anyone see where my code is failing please let me know.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? need to see how `resetSessionTimeout` `receiveUpdatedTimeRemaining` look like

Comment: have you tried if(!(target.is('a')) && !(target.data('type') == 'sign_in')) ?

Comment: Which jQuery modal plugin are you using please? I see no configuration for the modal at all. Are you providing any configuration of the modal?

Comment: @gmfm No, I will try now.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I use Bootstrap 3 modal. Not sure but I think I mentioned that above.

Comment: yep - sorry -missed

Comment: @Theo I do not have time now but will try to create jsfiddle later. Thank you.

Comment: @gmfm I have tried and still did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent your Modal dialog from closing on mouse click on the backdrop (anywhere on the page) you must configure it using this configuration:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-options

> Options can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript. For data attributes, append the option name to data-, as in data-backdrop="".

So it seems as simple as adding `data-backdrop="static"` to your modal `<div>`

If you prefer to do this in code, then you can do this:

```
$(...).modal({
  backdrop:'static',
  show: false // or true if you want to show it right now
})
```

**Edit**

To address the condition (I didn't understand):

if user logged in, then allow modal to close on any click
otherwise do not allow window to close.

It seems, given your code, the most reasonable place to accommodate this conditional would be in the `showBox()` function. Consider passing a second parameter to the function (or use some other source) that indicates if the user is logged in or not. Then:

```
function showBox(showIt, loggedIn) {
   let backdropClick = loggedIn ? true : 'static';
   let config = {backdrop: backdropClick, show: true}
   showIt 
     ? $('#sessiontimeoutwarning').modal(config) 
     : $('#sessiontimeoutwarning').modal('hide'); 
}
```

As one option.

Comment: I have tested your code and if I use js method modal will close if I click anywhere on the screen. If I add data-backdrop="static" to my div html then dialog will remain on the screen after I click anywhere in the background. That seems weird...

Comment: I'm quoting your question here: _... if they click anywhere on the page modal box is closed. I do not want modal box to close if session expiered._. The first step to achieving that is to prevent the box from closing so that you **do have** control over **when** it does/does not close.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your previous comment. Modal box is showing on the screen in two different situations. In first scenario modal is showing on the box and user should be able to click anywhere on the screen or click on the Continue button and modal box should close. Second scenario is after session expired. In that case box has only one option for user. They can click on the link to Return to the login page. If they try to click anywhere else box should not close. I hope this will explain the whole situation and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes that clarifies - let me look back at all that code of yours. Then I'll comment again.

Comment: @espresso_coffee - please see my revised answer